# How to force Apache to listen to a specific network

Tags: apache, wampserver

I have a Apache server (part of WAMP) that is open to request from the network.
I have two networks that I am using (192.168.1 and 192.168.2).
The Apache is listening only to the second network (192.168.2) even if it is off and I am connected to the first network.
I tried to change the "listen" parameter in the httpd.conf

```
Listen 198.162.1.77:80
```

But then when I restart the WAMP, its color indicates that it failed.

Comment: And what is in error log (or in event viewer) ?

Comment: There is no error.
The last line in the log is 
Child process 8780 exited successfully.
In normal case (when I comment this line and restore the other Listen lines) there are few more lines after that:
Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
...

Comment: BTW is `198.162.1.77` assigned to any of  interfaces?

Comment: As you only have one network card I dont think you can be on 2 subnets at the same time. However if you try `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` it should at least listen on which ever subnet you are currently connected to